# How to create a table that allows a user to type a time value only

Tags: sql, oracle, time, sqlplus

I have a table called time but im not sure how to just allow a user to type a time value in. For example: 10:30. I am using SQLPlus.

Comment: Are you new to database..are you not aware about datatypes?

Comment: No i am not new, its just that the 'Date' data type does not allow me just to enter in a time like '10:30' for example. It includes both the date and time together.